# training the face_recognition using kinect

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, face-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi , I try to run this package ""https://github.com/procrob/procrob_functional"" but when i execute the commands in this page """http://wiki.ros.org/face_recognition""" No images are added to the data folder ???
I am using fuerte distribution on Ubuntu 12.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/162831/training-the-face_recognition-using-kinect/) by [smart engineer](https://answers.ros.org/users/15051/smart-engineer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-05-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A lot of Fuerte stuff is broken and it's not being updated.  I would highly suggest looking into OpenCV or PCL for any sort of computer vision applications.

---

Originally posted by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) with karma: 429 on 2014-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [smart engineer](https://answers.ros.org/users/15051/smart-engineer/) on 2014-05-30**:
But ROS face _ Recognition package worked with other people using Fuerte distribution ???  and I am interesting in working with it ...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rosbuild version of the face_recognition package works for Fuetre. For more recent versions of ROS, you need to use the catkin version of the face_recognition package.

---

Originally posted by [Pouyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1471/pouyan/) with karma: 143 on 2014-11-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1